# Какой Raycast лучше использовать для мультиплеерного шутера?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Вопрос задаю чисто из-за интереса и чтобы лучше понять логику применения Raycast

Делаю мультиплеерный шутер и я знаю что есть два способа сделать стрельбу, через луч который идет из центра камеры(**метод ViewportPointToRay**) и через луч который идет из конкретной точки(в данном случае это дуло оружия, **через пустой объект и его transform**)

Так вот, собственно вопрос: Какой из этих вариантов лучше сделать? и в чем разница между ними?

Буду очень благодарен за любые комментарии, помочь, ресурсы где можно более подробно об этом узнать)

*Всем благ и хорошего настроения!*

Comment: Думаю если описывать разницу, рискуешь стать капитаном очевидностью. За всю историю шутеров были опробованы многие варианты, если не все и их больше чем два, даже с стрельбой которая называется `hitscan`. Этот вопрос не технический, а дизайнерский. `Stack` все-таки по технической части, а в интернетах, как грязи статей посвященных этому вопросу, все-таки шутеры это не ниша а доминирующий жанр.

Comment: @Yaroslav то есть любой из предложенных мною вариантов будет работать как надо? То есть посылать луч в центр экрана. Лучше больше позаботиться о том, какие характеристики, методы и приемы будут реализованы в стрельбе? Хорошо, я вас услышал, видимо мне не стоит так запариваться на счет Raycast'a, ибо до уровня ААА шутеров все равно не получиться дойти. :D